# Post request from Unity not receiving in php

Tags: c#, php, unity-game-engine

I am using POST request from Unity script to send a value to php script. The Unity script is able to send value but the php is not able to receive anything. I am even dumping the output message and what I get is

```
Notice:  Undefined index: myString in /var/www/clients/client1/web3/web/downloads/GetVal.php<br />
```

What mistake am I doing here that I am not even able to send a value? I even used isset() to check if a value is received in php, but to no luck.

Unity

```
 public void Send () {
        StartCoroutine ("SendValue");
        
    }

    IEnumerator SendValue() {
    string test = "ABC";
    WWWForm form = new WWWForm ();
    form.AddField ("myString", test);
    using (UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post ("localhost/GetVal.php?myString=" + test, form)) {
                www.chunkedTransfer = false;
                yield return www.SendWebRequest ();

                if (www.error == null) {
                    string responseText = www.downloadHandler.text;
                    Debug.Log ("Response Text from the server = " + responseText);
                } else {
                    Debug.Log (www.error);
                }
            }
   }
```

PHP

```
<?php 
session_start();
ob_start();

ini_set('display_errors', '1');
ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');
error_reporting(E_ALL);


if(empty($_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE']))
{ 
 $_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE'] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"; 
}

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

        $myString = htmlspecialchars($_POST["myString"]);
    
        var_dump($_POST);
}

?>
```

Comment: You are passing mystring as a get variable.

Comment: @BugFinder I even changed the url as ```UnityWebRequest.Post ("localhost/GetVal.php", form)``` but did not change anything.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing your string as a get variable. You should do:

```
htmlspecialchars($_GET["myString"]);
```

Or send your parameters as post parameters from Unity.